# How to force users to MFA when they login to the app via their Azure AD account?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, multi-factor-authentication

I added second login option (Microsoft Identity (Azure AD)) to my web app by following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30B7efdpNxI).

Briefly my Startup.cs as below

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(opt => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", opt));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, opt => {
   opt.Authority = opt.Authority + "/v2.0/";
   opt.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
});
```

and I can login via any Azure AD account to the app now. However, I also need MFA when the user enters his Azure AD username and password. Is there any Azure portal configuration or asp.net core configuration for this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings) , for configuring Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication settings. You can check out the verification methods available for the users and enable them in the azure portal. For more information you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#verification-methods).